# What is the max user load that can be taken by VS 2013 for a load test

Tags: performance, load-testing, visualstudio

We want to load test a web application for 550 users using VS 2013 ultimate.
A machine is a high-end machine with 32GB RAM and 6 cores processor. Is one machine enough for a load test of 550 users? or do I need to go for distributed load?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

VS2013 does not place any limits on the number of virtual users. That said, there are trade-offs.

**You may want to use distributed load tests if:**

- Your application or the test processing is resource-heavy.
- You need your virtual users to come from multiple IP addresses (this functionality is handled by test agents).
- Network bandwidth usage is one of the variables you are monitoring.
- You want to simulate different user agent strings
- Your load test includes different scenarios with different load profiles

**You may want to use single-system load tests if:**

- You don't care about having a single IP address per user
- You want to increase load until system failure (the fewer variables in the mix for this kind of test, the better, I've found)
- You don't need to check network bandwidth usage OR the bandwidth between your test machine and your app is enough to handle all your expected traffic

Answer (score 0):

The number of virtual users that one agent can support depends upon several things, but they amount to how much CPU and memory each user uses. Things that contribute include:

- Number of requests in the web test
- Duration of web test
- Number and complexity of extraction and verification rules, also of plugins

Some of the data recorded for each run of a web test is held in RAM until the web test completes. All this data adds up so the RAM may become exhausted with too many users on an agent.

Microsoft [have published](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937706.aspx) a guide to how many users an agent can support. It appears that the latest version of this guide has the same values as published in 2012. The recommendation is that a single 2.6GHz CPU with 2GB memory can support up to 500 users and a dual processor 2.6GHz CPU with 2GB memory can support up to 1000 users. Your 6 cores and 32GB memory should be ample.

Remember to specify `Run tests in 64 bit process on 64 bit machine` in the `Hosts` section of the active ".testsettings" for the test run.